# iOS - View Controller With Container Views - Hide Keyboard

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a view controller that has 3 container views. In one of the container views, there's a text field, tapping on which the keyboard should get hidden. I need to know how to hide the keyboard when ever the touch is detected on the view controller. Please note that the "touchesBegan" method doesn't get called on the parentViewController when I tap on a container view.

Comment: You want to hide the keyboaed when you tap the screen outside of the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

Implement touchesBegan on your view controller.  From there call endEditing on the view controller's view:

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
     [self.view endEditing: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITapGesture.

in your viewcontroller's viewDidLoad write this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: singleTap];
```

and at its handler method

```
 -(void)handleSingleTap :(UIGestureRecognizer*)ges
{
 [yourtextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the viewController's UIView and the other container UIViews to UIButton, then bind them to one of the button's touch events to an IBAction with the following code:

```
-(IBAction)press:(id)sender
{
   [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: No. Like I mentioned in the question, there are three container views in that screen and I want this to work even if the user clicks on any container view on the screen.

Comment: change your container views to buttons too, and bind them all to the function, even if you are adding your containers programmatically you can define them as UIButton and bind them to them function

Comment: What a kludgey solution.